# spark withColumn fails on creating new dataframe when done in a loop

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

i have a dataframe where i have split it into a "matchedDF" and an "unmatchedDF" based on a columnid that meets a criteria.  that works; then i have a collection of columns in an array that I do a foreach on to update matching columns in the matchedDF and transform the results to a new DF (because i know DF's are immutable).  the problem happens with the creation of the newrow object when i want to have the loop point to the column that will be updated.  there is an issue with the looping and the withColumn will not work, I get

> notebook:6: error: not found: value $x
>     var newrow = matchDF.withColumn($x, lit("0")).toDF()

this is on azure databricks 5.2 (includes Apache Spark 2.4.0, Scala 2.11). I am able to do this w/o the lamda/foreach, but that is a one-off and i have more than one column to work with.

```
var notmatchDF = df.filter(!$"id".rlike (regexString)).toDF()

var matchDF = df.filter($"id".rlike (regexString)).toDF()

columnControl.foreach(x => {
  var newrow = matchDF.withColumn($x, lit("0")).toDF()
  val appended = notmatchDF.union(newrow).toDF()
})
```

my expectation is that the columns provided in the columnControl will be set to "0" in the newrow dataframe that can then be appended to the notmatchDF

Comment: You have done typo mistake here, use it like this `var newrow = matchDF.withColumn($"x", lit("0")).toDF()`

Comment: ok, thanks - the fixed typo resolves the replace when done outside of the loop (not having it executed in the foreach); however, i still get an error when executed within the loop:  
`
notebook:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.ColumnName
 required: String
  var newrow = matchDF.withColumn($"x", lit("0")).toDF()
`
is this because i am addressing this in a new DF that once declared will not allow a subsequent update?  i think i need to research how to continually apply updates to a dataframe then.